# No-thread bound request found

Tags: java, spring, jetty, jax-rs, cxf

Using Apache CXF dependency `cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty-3.1.4.jar` to test JAXRS services. Below are the Junit annotations-

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-spring-context.xml"})
```

**web.xml** (don't think web.xml is loaded by `@WebAppConfiguration` but it's in standard directory src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml)

```
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- listener to inject HttpServlet Request -->
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- CXF Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Jetty configuration**-

```
<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf" id="port9191">
    <httpj:engine port="9191">
        <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="5"
            maxThreads="15" />
        <httpj:handlers>
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler" />
        </httpj:handlers>
        <httpj:sessionSupport>true</httpj:sessionSupport>
    </httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>
```

Getting below exception while trying to read header from `@Autowired HttpServletRequest request` object `request.getHeader("ApplicationName");`-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:309) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.access$400(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:64) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:325) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:320) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AutowireUtils$ObjectFactoryDelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(AutowireUtils.java:307) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: _src/main/webapp/web.xml_ is not the standard location. Put it in _src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml_. Maybe that's the reason it doesn't notice you've declared RequestContextListener as a listener.

Comment: mistakenly i had put wrong path in post. It is inside src/main/webapp/WEB-INF only. I have updated the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpServletRequest injected through JAX-RS ContainerRequestFilter.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

@Provider
public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private static final String REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES_ATTRIBUTE =
            RequestFilter.class.getName() + ".REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES";

    @Context private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(httpRequest);
        httpRequest.setAttribute(REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES_ATTRIBUTE, attributes);
        LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(httpRequest.getLocale());
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attributes);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more insight what exactly helped you here and what you fixed?